# Filter formula in excel

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have a table called Store. Its Action column have four unique entries: NEW, REMOVED, RE-ADDED, and PRICE CHANGED. I have an EFFECTIVE column that contains the date of when the action was made.

I have a ITEMS column that have the name of the items that the store is selling.

I need help to create a formula that will filter the unique items that are available as of today. I plan on using this as a list for data validation of the available items.

sample sheet:

[image: sample sheet]

I tried using the a simple FILTER formula and tried to exclude rows that has REMOVED entries but my problem is that it still show the earlier items with NEW entries in the action column. Kindly help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following formula-

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C11,MAP(C2:C11,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(x,C2:C11,A2:A11,,0,-1)))<>"Removed"))
```

[image]

Comment: Got something very similar just a bit shorter: =LET(a,UNIQUE(G2:G11),z,XLOOKUP(a,G2:G11,E2:E11,,0,-1),FILTER(a,z<>"REMOVED")) also both formulas will work if list is sorted ascending by its effective date. Otherwise sorting must be done

Answer (score 0):

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(Store[ITEMS], (Store[ACTION]="NEW" OR Store[ACTION]="READDED") AND Store[EFFECTIVE]<=TODAY() AND (Store[ACTION]<>"REMOVED" OR Store[EFFECTIVE]=MAXIFS(Store[EFFECTIVE], Store[ITEMS], Store[ITEMS], Store[ACTION]="REMOVED"))))
```

Please note that you need to replace  with the actual name of your table, lick `Store`
This formula filters items where the action is either `NEW` or `READDED`, the effective date is less than or equal to today, and the action is not `REMOVED` or the effective date is the maximum effective date for `REMOVED` actions.